# Catch click event on map, but on nothing else

Tags: javascript, leaflet

My map has some stuff like points, lines, etc... and I want to remove some layers on the map when the user clicks on another part of the map, as follow:

```
map.on({
   click: function(event) {
      removePolylines.call(this);
      hidePopup.call(this);
   }.bind(this),
});
```

That **removePolylines** method, I wish to trigger it only when you click on the map, but not when you click on a line or point. How can I distinguish when click event is fired? 
I mean, I want to remove the lines when you click on nothing else but the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jquery you can simply use the event.target. [Official jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vs0sbw5p/) is a working example